# SQL how to count unique values that meet specific criteria, and exclude them from the count if their repeating duplicates don't meet my criteria

Tags: sql, count, distinct-values, unique-values

I have a table with **user_id's** and number of **impressions** they received during a certain period of time. A new record is added to the table when there is a new impression. Ex below:

| user_id | impressions |
| --- | --- |
| #1 | 0 |
| #2 | 0 |
| #3 | 1 |
| #3 | 2 |
| #3 | 3 |
| #2 | 1 |

**Question: how to count unique user_id's, who received less than 3 impressions during this period of time using SQL?**

If I use COUNT DISTINCT + WHERE impressions < 3, I will get the result

user_id's = 3 (#1, #2, #3),     as it will count the first occurrence of #3 that meets my criteria and count it in.

But the right answer would be user_id's = 2 (#1 and #2) because only they received less than 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
select user_id, sum(impressions) as impressions
from $your_table
where $your_date_field between $start_period and $end_period -- period of time
group by user_id
having sum(impressions) < 3
```

Replace "`$`" table/fields with real ones (unknown in your question)

Comment: thank you! This one gives an "Aggregation of aggregation" mistake though.

Comment: You are welcome. Basically, if you want to filter your data once aggregated, you must use the `having` clause. The `where` clause applies before the grouping stage. If the answer is correct please mark it. Thank you

Comment: And what if I want to get a result of those users grouping them by month (for example: 3 users (with imp < 3) in May; 5 users in June; 2 users in July)?

Comment: Then you need to `count(user_id)`, `sum(impressions)` and show and group by `year($your_date_field)`, `month($your_date_field)`

Answer (score 0):

```
with
max_impressions_per_user_id as 
(
select 
    user_id,
    max(impressions) as max_impressions
from table 
group by user_id
)
select count(*)
from max_impressions_per_user_id 
where max_impressions < 3
;
```

Comment: This one worked, thank you!